# nothing in my docker, but it consumes all my root space

Tags: linux, docker, docker-container, dcm4che

I'm running dcm4chee in docker and I bind mount a container storage with my harddisk. A problem is when people send me data, it seems like the data is stored to two locations, harddisk and docker storage. Right now, my root directory runs out of space and there is also nothing in docker root directory. I want to store the data only in my harddisk, what should I do?

```
#df -h

Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   50G   14M 100% /
overlay                   50G   50G   14M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/b802b19d61525cb8fee5a86e37128a731cfa6ca3ba1635bf722ff2301c79c63e/merged
overlay                   50G   50G   14M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae/merged
overlay                   50G   50G   14M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3dd73139201d57f47b055a57729685cbaab17dd016ce615501f5e7d028094684/merged
overlay                   50G   50G   14M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged

#docker info 2>/dev/null |grep -E "Server Version:|Kernel Version:|Operating System:|Docker Root Dir:"

Server Version: 20.10.14
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Docker Root Dir: /home1/PACS/docker

#folderroot=$(docker info 2>/dev/null |grep -E "Docker Root Dir:"| sed "s# Docker Root Dir:\s/#/#g")
#du -ah "$folderroot"/ 2>/dev/null | sort -rh | head -n 20

4.7G    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2
4.7G    /home1/PACS/docker/
1.3G    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged
1.3G    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238
962M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae
895M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae/merged
695M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged/opt
668M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae/merged/opt
531M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged/usr
445M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged/usr/lib
417M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
398M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/4cf0b7c9e2b42e1e6983e55cc1d7764c446392d8812a4086b8bc86d380930ea0/diff
398M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/4cf0b7c9e2b42e1e6983e55cc1d7764c446392d8812a4086b8bc86d380930ea0
391M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/4cf0b7c9e2b42e1e6983e55cc1d7764c446392d8812a4086b8bc86d380930ea0/diff/usr
388M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged/opt/wildfly
371M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3dd73139201d57f47b055a57729685cbaab17dd016ce615501f5e7d028094684/merged
371M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3dd73139201d57f47b055a57729685cbaab17dd016ce615501f5e7d028094684
366M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/4cf0b7c9e2b42e1e6983e55cc1d7764c446392d8812a4086b8bc86d380930ea0/diff/usr/lib
365M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/4cf0b7c9e2b42e1e6983e55cc1d7764c446392d8812a4086b8bc86d380930ea0/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
361M    /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae/merged/opt/keycloak
```

A folder `/home1/PACS/docker` is docker root directory which is in mounted path to my harddisk.

**update**

`docker system prune -a` does not free up space in root, result is `Total reclaimed space: 169.9MB` (what it does is only remove my docker images) and `df -h` is still the same.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   50G  171M 100% /
overlay                   50G   50G  171M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/b802b19d61525cb8fee5a86e37128a731cfa6ca3ba1635bf722ff2301c79c63e/merged
overlay                   50G   50G  171M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/65abae265e1bd672a5ab5171dae5e699a2b9d1dc3fc0003d9c96f1e55bc2daae/merged
overlay                   50G   50G  171M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3dd73139201d57f47b055a57729685cbaab17dd016ce615501f5e7d028094684/merged
overlay                   50G   50G  171M 100% /home1/PACS/docker/overlay2/3984d7d093121c5213e9b2e7345549df049e93158a89e6628f3861a01d7a1238/merged
```

Although all my containers are removed, it still does not free up.

Answer (score -1):

`docker system prune -a`

it cleans all unuse images and containers and volumes

Comment: This won't have any effect on disk usage by user data in volumes.

Comment: It does not help, the command only removes docker images.